# Cache-control apache error

Tags: apache-2.2, cache

I've put in **httpd.conf**

```
# 480 weeks
<filesmatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=290304000, public"
</filesmatch>

# 2 days
<filesmatch "\.(xml|txt)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=172800, public, must-revalidate"
</filesmatch>

# 2 hours
<filesmatch "\.(html|htm)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, must-revalidate"
</filesmatch>
```

but when I run `/etc/init.d/apache restart` (in Debian 6.0) I get:

```
Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/httpd.conf:
Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
 failed!
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use `Header` directive you need to load [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_headers.html):

```
sudo a2enmod headers
```

Comment: `a2enmod headers` fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Line 3? Try moving the above config to the end of your httpd.conf. The necessary modules haven't loaded yet at the top of the file. Also it's good to put snippets like this up and over in files under /etc/apache2/conf.d, so you're not modifying stock files, but you can tackle that after.

Comment: What module should I load?

Comment: Googling for "apache Header" yielded mod_headers, so I'd check for that. I'd be surprised if it wasn't already loaded. For example my Apache has "LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so".